# Comparing the lengths of two segments between a point on the diameter of a circle and the circle

Tags: geometry, circles

Let $C$ be a circle with center at $O$. Let $D$ and $E$ be two mutually perpendicular diameters of $C$. Let $P$ be a point on $D$ that is different than $O$, and of the two points of intersection of $D$ with $C$, denote by $A$ the one that is farther from $P$. Let $B$ denote one of the points of intersection of $E$ with $C$. Denote by $Z$ that arc of $C$ that is enclosed by the *right* angle $\angle AOB$. Let $X$ be any point on $Z$ that is different than $B$. How can it be shown that $PX$ is (strictly) greater than $PB$?

[image: An illustration]

Comment: Hint: Law of Sines.

Comment: One may use also rule, that greater side of triangle is opposite to greatest angle

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: This reduces the problem to showing that $\angle PXB < \angle PBX$. But how do I show this?

Comment: Compare them both with angle $OBX=OXB$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: I'm sorry. I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: $\angle PBX=\angle PBO+\angle OBX > \angle OBX = \angle OXB \geq \angle OXB-\angle OXP = \angle PXB$

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu: Thank you very much. Now I get it.